# Как отобразить граф в виде правильной треугольной решетки в networkx

Tags: python, графы, визуализация, networkx

Нужно отобразить граф в виде такой решетки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно установить какой-то определенный layout или есть другой способ?

Comment: Приведите данные, по которым вы строите граф. Или у вас данных нет, но вы хотите построить граф такого вида? Я просто думаю, что если будет граф с такой связностью, то может он и сам в таком виде построится. Но нужно смотреть.